# problems retrieving attribute from MBean

Tags: java, attributes, jmx

I try to access a String attribute `Token` from an MBean in JBoss7.  I can verify that the MBean is registered and the getter `String getToken()` is part of the interface.  `mbServer` holds the mbean server and `objName` the correct `ObjectName`.

I try three methods to access the attribute. The second one fails.

1. `final String token1 = (String)mbServer.getAttribute(objName, "Token");` succeeds
2. `final String token2 = (String)mbServer.invoke(ojbName, "getToken", new Object[]{}, new String[]{});` => `ReflectionException, No such operation: getToken`
3. This one works:

   ```
   final MyMBean mbean = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbServer, objName, MyMBean.class);
   final String token3 = mbean.getToken();
   ```

Why does the second one fail?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For #1, the attribute name should be "Token"

Comment: Indeed, changing the attirbute name to 'Token' and calling 'final String token1 = (String)mbServer.getAttribute(objName, "Token");' succeeds. But it is ugly, as field name starting with an uppercase letter are deprecated.